# Cannot read the subnodes with PHP of an XML file

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am reading an XML file with PHP as follows:

```
$this->dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $strbody );
$xp = new \DOMXPath($this->dom);

foreach( $xp->query('//div | //ul | //ol') as $node) {
    array_push($nodes, $node);
}
// Further processing of the individual elements.
// "2 loop".
foreach( $nodes as $node) 
{
    echo "node: " . print_r($node, true) . PHP_EOL;  
}
```

Via the **2 loop** I want to access sub-knead.
From this node I can output the attributes with:

```
foreach ( $node->attributes as $nodeValue )
{
    echo "attributes: ".print_r($nodeValue, true).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Or I can also print out the child nodes:

```
foreach ( $node->childNodes as $nodeValue )
{
    echo "childNodes: ".print_r($nodeValue, true).PHP_EOL;
}
```

But how can I access the child nodes?
Here is the structure of the XML file:

```
<startxml system="https://bspurl.de" sprache="DE">
    <inhalt bez="body" sprache="DE">
            <objekt type="xhtml">
                </div class="text">
                    sadf gfew
                </div>
                <div class="h2">Überschrift</div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <span class="bold">Weitere Infos:</span>
                    </div>
                </div class="text">
                    asf 43 rfedv34asd
                </div>
            </objekt>
        </inhalt>    
</startxml>
```

I need to access the **span** (< span class="bold">Weitere Infos:< /span >) element, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `DOMXpath::evaluate()/query()` is the context node for the Xpath expression. So you can address nodes relative to the current node.

`DOMNode::$textContent` returns the text content of a node including its descendant nodes.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<startxml system="https://bspurl.de" sprache="DE">
    <inhalt bez="body" sprache="DE">
        <objekt type="xhtml">
            <div class="text">before</div>
            <div class="h2">Überschrift</div>
            <div class="text">
                <span class="bold">Weitere Infos:</span>
            </div>
            <div class="text">after</div>
        </objekt>
    </inhalt>    
</startxml>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMxpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//div') as $div) {
    var_dump('DIV: ', $div->textContent);
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('.//span[@class="bold"]', $div) as $span) {
        var_dump('SPAN:', $span->textContent);
    }
}
```

`DOMxpath::evaluate()` can return scalar values. This allows to cast the value in Xpath:

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//objekt[@type="xhtml"]') as $objekt) {
        var_dump(
            $xpath->evaluate(
                'string(.//div[@class="h2"]/following-sibling::*//span[@class="bold"])', 
                $objekt
            )
        );
}
```